# Write CSV To File Without Enclosures In PHP

Tags: php, csv, quotes, quoting

Is there a native function or solid class/library for writing an array as a line in a CSV file without enclosures? `fputcsv` will default to `"` if nothing is passed in for the enclosure param. Google is failing me (returning results for a whole bunch of pages about `fputcsv`), and PEAR's libraries do more or less the same things as `fputcsv`.

Something that works exactly like `fputcsv`, but will allow the fields to remain unquoted.

currently: `"field 1","field 2",field3hasNoSpaces`

desired: `field 1,field 2,field3hasNoSpaces`

Comment: I think you need the quotes.. what if there is a newline character or comma in there and they are not quote delimited?

Comment: Quotes are there for your benefit.  It's a good practice to use them; that's why they are the default.

Comment: I disagree; if you have control of the input data you may wish to omit the enclosures, particularly if you may be exporting all numeric/filtered string data to an archaic reader. The other thing is tab separated files: Don't need enclosures.

Comment: If you're generating a CSV to be used to upload data to a poorly built app the quotes may interfere with the sql.. as is my situation

Comment: fputcsv appears to have a bug that causes this sort of thing:

3StartssWithNum,"StartsWithAlpha", "notherStartsWAlpha", etc.

The enclosure char is not the issue. The inconsistency is. [PHP ver 5.6]

Comment: I made it to get no delimiters by specifying `chr(0)` as delimiter in the last argument

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The warnings about foregoing enclosures are valid, but you've said they don't apply to your use-case.

I'm wondering why you can't just use something like this?

```
<?php
$fields = array(
    "field 1","field 2","field3hasNoSpaces"
);
fputs(STDOUT, implode(',', $fields)."\n");
```

Comment: Dunno why I didn't go to this first. Thanks!

Comment: Because CSV libraries handle cases that your simple implode solution doen't, like scaping the separator character (`,` in your case).

Comment: This is the best way to replace fputcsv without enclosures. I would make a small suggestion to improve this answer - use documented argument order for [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) : `implode(string $glue, array $pieces)` to avoid confusion with people who are new to PHP and don't know this PHP "feature" of reversed arguments.

Comment: `fputs(...)` is an alias function, consider using `fwrite(...)` instead.

Answer (score 11):

works with **chr()** function:

```
fputcsv($f,$array,',',chr(0));
```

Comment: chr(0) create null char who is display in utf8 like ^@

Comment: I doubt this is a good idea. You're actually writing a `"\0"`. Mostly invisible until it comes back to bite you.

Comment: Notepad on Windows will open a file with "\0" characters with the wrong encoding, leading to garbage characters shown on screen.

Comment: What about you delete this very wrong answer which is sitting here since 9 years?

Answer (score 6):

`fputcsv($file, $data, ';', chr(127));`

Comment: That was the one I was looking for. Thanks m8!

Comment: Actually, chr(127) still shows as a character in the file so it isn't ideal. Damn

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php       
    
$filename = "sample.csv";
$handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
fputcsv($handle, ['column 1','column 2']);
$data = ['sample','data'];

fputs($handle, implode(',', $data)."\n");

// or

fwrite($handle, implode(',', $data)."\n");

fclose($handle);
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
);
```

Comment: Spot on! Why people are always looking for some nifty one-liner that makes the code hard to maintain instead of relying on basic built-in functions to do it the right way?

Answer (score 2):

Well `car(0)` didn't work out as the `NULL` value will most likely choke most csv parsers.

I ended using `fputcsv()` to build the initial file, then went through and removed all quotes. Elegant? Maybe not, but it got the job done :).

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this work?

```
fputcsv($fp, split(',', $line),',',' ');
```

Comment: Split will be a deprecated function and this doesn't necessarily solve my issue with enclosures. Unfortunately spaces aren't considered a legit character at least as far as this function is concerned. Thanks though!

Comment: Assuming the extra space isn't a problem, it seems he's looking for *no* enclosure; however, using a space seems like the logical thing to try.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to put standard CSV into an array...

```
function csv_explode($delim=',', $str, $enclose='"', $preserve=false){
        $resArr = array();
        $n = 0;
        $expEncArr = explode($enclose, $str);
        foreach($expEncArr as $EncItem){
                if($n++%2){
                        array_push($resArr, array_pop($resArr) . ($preserve?$enclose:'') . $EncItem.($preserve?$enclose:''));
                }else{
                        $expDelArr = explode($delim, $EncItem);
                        array_push($resArr, array_pop($resArr) . array_shift($expDelArr));
                        $resArr = array_merge($resArr, $expDelArr);
                }
        }
        return $resArr;
}
```

You can then output whatever you want in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

The downside with a CSV file with no enclosures means an errant comma in user input will munge the row. So you'll need to remove commas before writing a CSV row.

The tricky part with handling CSV is parsing enclosures, which makes the PHP & PEAR CSV functions valuable. Essentially you're looking for a file that is comma-delimited for columns and newline-delimited for rows. Here's a simple starting point:

```
<?php
$col_separator= ',';
$row_separator= "\n";

$a= array(
 array('my', 'values', 'are', 'awes,breakit,ome'),
 array('these', 'values', 'also', "rock\nAND\nROLL")
);

function encodeRow(array $a) {
 global $col_separator;
 global $row_separator;
 // Can't have the separators in the column data!
 $a2= array();
 foreach ($a as $v) {
  $a2[]= str_replace(array($col_separator, $row_separator), '', $v);
 }
 return implode($col_separator, $a2);
}

$output= array();
foreach ($a as $row) {
 $output[]= encodeRow($row);
}

echo(implode($row_separator, $output));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use tricky way to remove double quote, but only in Linux

```
....
fputcsv($fp, $product_data,"\t");
....
shell_exec('sed -i \'s/"//g\' /path/to/your-file.txt ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with good old fwrite()?

```
function encloseString($field){
    return ($field) ? '"' . $field . '"' : null;
}

$delimiter = ';';
$data = ["data_field_1", "data_field_2", "data_field_3"];

$fp = fopen("some-file.csv", 'w');

for($i = 0;$i<100000;$i++) {
    fwrite($fp, implode($delimiter, array_map('encloseString', $data) . "\n");
}

fclose($fp);
```

(Obviously you need to make sure the data in $data is escaped first)

Answer (score 0):

Chose the solution depends on your application. For some case own code for csv is needed. In case 1 (See result [chr0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jc4h.png)), case 2 ([chr127](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmT4m.png)) and case 3 ([chr127](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmT4m.png)) the data will be modified(bad thing). Instead use something like this, thanks @oops:

```
<?php
$fields = array("field 1","field 2","field3hasNoSpaces");
fputs(STDOUT, implode(',', $fields)."\n");
```

- case 1. `fputcsv($f, $array, $delimiter, car(0))` See result [chr0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jc4h.png)
- case 2. `fputcsv($f, $array, $delimiter, car(127))`
  [chr127](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmT4m.png)
- case 3. `fputcsv($f, $array, $delimiter, ' ')`
  [onespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuAsC.png)
- case 4. Own code (s.above inspired by
  [oops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1904945)  or
  [Ansyori](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51981613)  or
  [zeros-and-ones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38778459) ) produces
  better results.

Comment: Did you intend `chr(0)` and `chr(197)` ?   I solved this issue with the first one.

Comment: yes, [chr0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jc4h.png) for chr(0) and so on...

Answer (score -1):

**`chr(0)`** also worked for me:

```
 fputcsv($fp, $aLine, $sDelimiter, chr(0));
```

Comment: I think it work's because your editor don't show you the null char, but it's still there

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question but as I was struggling with this as well, I thought it would be good to let anyone who is looking for something like this know than you can just pass empty string in the **enclosure** param of fputcsv and it will not use any enclosure at all.

i.e.

> fputcsv($file, $array, ',', '');

Comment: Passing an empty string for the `enclosure` parameter throws the "enclosure must be a character" error, which is the very reason the author posted the question in the first place

Answer (score -3):

Figured it out. By passing in the ascii code for Null to the `car()` function it seems to work just fine.

`fputcsv($f, $array, $delimiter, car(0))`

Thanks for the answers everyone!!!

Comment: Hmm... are you sure it's not gonna put a bunch of stealth nulls in the csv file? :s Also, I think it's 'chr(0)' --!

Comment: Puts NULL for me. Not the ideal solution.

Comment: `car(0)` really??