# Remove quotes from element during saving csv

Tags: php, csv

I have next problem: when I save a line into my csv file, I use

```
fputcsv($this->_streamHandler, $row, $delimiter, $enclosure);
```

where:

```
$enclosure = '"'
$delimite= "#";
$row = array("somemail@gmail.com", "someName", "2014-01-29 10:13:35");
```

So, after this I have next line in my file:

```
somemail@gmail.com#someName#"2014-01-29 10:13:35"
```

Why `date` element (2014-01-29 10:13:35) saved with quotes to file?

If I set `$enclosure = ''`, 
fputcsv return false, if I set another symbol, for example`"-"`, it wil save line with `'-'` at the beginning of each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you providing a delimiter or an enclosure?  You are telling it separate your fields using #.  Remove the two optional arguments.  They are for overiding the delimiter and enclosure characters.

```
     fputcsv($this->_streamHandler, $row);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

If your date is already quoted, you need to remove any prexisting quotes:

```
    $row[2] = str_replace('"', '', $row[2]);
```

Look here for a similar SO question: [Avoid default quotes from csv file when using fputcsv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516811/avoid-default-quotes-from-csv-file-when-using-fputcsv)

Comment: The problem is that 2014-01-29 10:13:35 write with quotes!!

Comment: The date is inside the array, which your passing through to function. Remove the delimiter and enclosure. They are not needed.

Comment: NO!! I need delimeter!

Comment: Why?  From the example you have given you do not.

Comment: Even, as in your example, It also saved in this way "2014-01-29 10:13:35"!!

Comment: Seems like someone else had a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516811/avoid-default-quotes-from-csv-file-when-using-fputcsv