# How delete quotes from str_pad in PHP

Tags: php, string, quotes

I'm writting file and in a field, I need write 6 caracters from number and complete with space.
I use then str_pad

```
str_pad($globalResult['Folio'], 6, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

But In my file I see it's adding quotes around my field. I put for example 6 and I've in return "     6". I want same but without quotes.

I try

```
trim(str_pad($globalResult['Folio'], 6, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT),'"')
```

Or

```
str_pad($globalResult['Folio'], 6, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT))
```

But I've always "     6" in my file.

I try $globalResult['Folio'] only I've 6.

Thanks for your help

### Update

Here a little more code:

```
$df = fopen("facturation/PDF/Export/ECRITURE.WIN", 'w');

//BOUCLE D'AFFICHAGE DES FACTURES====
//On parcourt la liste des factures
$DB_GLOBAL->DbQuery($req)or die(mysql_error());
$NumRow=1;
while($globalResult = $DB_GLOBAL->DbNextRow())
{
    $inf = [$globalResult['Typ'],$globalResult['Dte'],str_pad($globalResult['Folio'], 6, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT), str_pad($NumRow, 6, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT)];
    fputcsv($df, $inf, '|');
    $NumRow++;
}
if (fclose($df) === true) {
echo 'Fichier cree';

} else {
      echo 'Erreur : contactez l\'administrateur.';
}
```

And the result in file

> VE|05012015|"     1"|"     1"
>   VE|05012015|"     1"|"     2"
>   VE|05012015|"     1"|"     3"
>   VE|06012015|"     1"|"     4"
>   VE|06012015|"     1"|"     5"
>   VE|06012015|"     1"|"     6"
>   VE|06012015|"     1"|"     7"
>   VE|07012015|"     1"|"     8"
>   VE|07012015|"     1"|"     9"
>   VE|07012015|"     1"|"    10"
>   VE|08012015|"     1"|"    11"
>   VE|08012015|"     1"|"    12"
>   VE|08012015|"     1"|"    13"
>   VE|08012015|"     1"|"    14"
>   VE|08012015|"     1"|"    15"
>   VE|09012015|"     1"|"    16"
>   VE|09012015|"     1"|"    17"
>   VE|09012015|"     1"|"    18"
>   VE|09012015|"     1"|"    19"
>   VE|10012015|"     1"|"    20"
>   VE|10012015|"     1"|"    21"

I try to force enclosure parameter of fputcsv, "\n", "\0", null but nothing like I want. I need to export some datas on another application. I need to respect format asked

Comment: `str_pad` does not write to file, maybe problem in write function?

Comment: str_pad does not add quotes, see https://eval.in/509448

Comment: Don't take me for a dumb, please. I know str_pad is not for writting in a file... I use fputcsv. But I written severals integer or date field without problem. I just describe where my problem is... And I show severals options I find on stackOverflow to delete quote, but no success. It's why I ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800675/write-csv-to-file-without-enclosures-in-php)

```
fputs($df, implode($inf, ',')."\n");
```

Work perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Use intval to convert a string to an integer number:

```
$folio_int = intval(str_pad($globalResult['Folio'], 6, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT));
```

`fputcsv` encloses all strings that contain either whitespace (a space) or the encapsulation character (usually `"`).
You can either save it as integer (and lose your space), or use `fputs` and construct the csv file yourself. The problem has nothing to do with `str_pad` and only is because of the `fputcsv` function.

Comment: I try your solution, but it's deleting space I just add with str_pad. I've a number to complete on 6 caracters with space on the left.

Comment: It ads the " because you save it in csv format and fputcsv always encapsulate strings, since you want to preserve the space it will always add the " around it. You can better use `fputs` and construct the csv file yourself.